# ZipArchive zip particular folder but not the root folder in Laravel

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am  trying to zip all files and folders, and it works fine in local XAMPP, but in Server it only works for the particular given Folder, not the root.

My function for zipping **public** folder containing folders and files which is in `/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html/public`:

```
public function downloadProjectZip()
    {
         
        $rootPath = realpath('public');
        $exclusions=array(''); 
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach($files as $name=>$file){
            if(!$file->isDir() && !in_array($file->getFilename(),$exclusions)){
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
            }
        }

        $zip->close();
        $fileurl = 'file.zip';
        if (file_exists($fileurl)) {
            return response()->download($fileurl, config('app.SITE_NAME').'-Project.zip', array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
        } 
    }
```

But When I `$rootPath = realpath('')` or `$rootPath = realpath('/home/admin/web/oyebesmartest.com/public_html:/home/')` for root, it gives me error:

```
SplFileInfo::isDir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html/..) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/abc.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)
```

I gave **777** permission to ..public_html/*
and for check, I also gave 777 permission to abc.com/* but does not work.

How can I improve this function or alternative way to zip all files and folders of public_html/*